# python - strange behavior of scipy.stats.rankdata

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, ranking

Is there an explanation of the following output?

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as ss
In [2]: ss.rankdata([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5])
Out [2]: array([1. , 2. , 4. , 4. , 6.5, 4. , 6.5, 8. ])
```

I was expected the following output, without decimals for the rankings.

```
Out [2]: array([1. , 2. , 4. , 4. , 6., 4. , 6., 8. ])
```

Also, why are the rankings of type float instead of type int?

Comment: Take another look at the [`rankdata` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html).  In particular, note the `method` argument.  Then scroll down to the "Examples" section to see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the SciPy webpage [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html), the default `method` is `'average'` which returns the average of the ranks. Try other options of `method`.